# How to add Rectangle to menu item in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I was customizing the menu item with a rectangle. I need to remove all the characteristics in the default menu item and add the custom rectangle into the menu. I wasn't sure what property of menu item should be override? Any help?

Answer (score 2):

define a template like this:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="customMenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <WrapPanel Background="Gray" Margin="3">
            <Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="16"/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

then use it as the Template of any menu item.

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Template="{StaticResource customMenuItem}" Header="some text"/>
</Menu>
```